# Is the phrase "to do a surgery on" feasible?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I would like to ask if saying (figuratively) something like "We can do a surgery on this object so that ...". My question is about the phrase "to do a surgery on"; does that make sense to American native ears?

Comment: My advice: skip the indefinite article. "We can do surgery on this ..." would work. Or use *perform* instead of *do*.

Comment: What is the "object"?

Answer (score 1):

In English, you sometimes hear "do surgery on" but, more typically, we'd say "perform surgery on."